# Php Excel DateStamd Formatted date

Tags: phpexcel

I am reading an xlsx file and the fields are in DateStamd I want to convert them to a date data here I leave my progress

Excel A1 = 43160
Converte date = 01/03/2018

`enter code here`require '../PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php'; 
 require '../cnx/conection.php';

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('../../date.xlsx');

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$numRows = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();
for ($i = 2; $i <= $numRows; $i++) {

    $pm = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$i)->getValue();
  echo  $pm;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO regfecha (reg_fecha) VALUES('$pm')";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
}
```

`
here I have another example and I do not know how to apply it

`

## DATEVALUE

### Converts a date in the form of text to a serial number.

`

```html
<?php

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../../../../Classes/');

include 'PHPExcel.php';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

// Add some data
$testDates = array( '26 March 2012', '29 Feb 2012', 'April 1, 2012', '25/12/2012',
     '2012-Oct-31',  '5th November', 'January 1st',  'April 2012',
     '17-03',   '03-2012',  '29 Feb 2011',  '03-05-07',
     '03-MAY-07',  '03-13-07',
      );
$testDateCount = count($testDates);

for($row = 1; $row <= $testDateCount; ++$row) {
 $worksheet->setCellValue('A'.$row, $testDates[$row-1]);
 $worksheet->setCellValue('B'.$row, '=DATEVALUE(A'.$row.')');
 $worksheet->setCellValue('C'.$row, '=B'.$row);
}

$worksheet->getStyle('C1:C'.$testDateCount)
        ->getNumberFormat()
      ->setFormatCode('yyyy-mmm-dd');


echo '<hr />';


// Test the formulae
?>
<p><strong>Warning: </strong>The PHPExcel DATEVALUE() function accepts a wider range of date formats than MS Excel's DATEFORMAT() function.</p>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
  <th>Date String</th>
  <th>Formula</th>
  <th>Excel DateStamp</th>
  <th>Formatted DateStamp</th>
 </tr>
 <?php
 for ($row = 1; $row <= $testDateCount; ++$row) {
  echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>' , $worksheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getFormattedValue() , '</td>';
   echo '<td>' , $worksheet->getCell('B'.$row)->getValue() , '</td>';
   echo '<td>' , $worksheet->getCell('B'.$row)->getFormattedValue() , '</td>';
   echo '<td>' , $worksheet->getCell('C'.$row)->getFormattedValue() , '</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Have you looked at any of the functions in the `PHPExcel_Shared_Date` class, like `ExcelToPHP()` that will convert an Excel timestamp to a unix timestamp that you can format with PHP's `date()` function; or `ExcelToPHPObject()` that will convert an Excel timestamp to a PHP DateTime object that yo can format using it's `format() method

Comment: Or have you considered using `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$i)->getFormattedValue();` instead of `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$i)->getValue();`